# initramfs unpacking failed: write error

Tags: boot, 16.04, iso, initramfs

I'm attempting to put Ubuntu on an old HP Pavilion zt1130, which has a Celeron i686 processor.  I used an Ubuntu MATE 16.04 disk that was lying around.  However, I got the error:

```
initramfs unpacking failed: write error
```

I've seen this before, and so I got a blank DVD and burned a new copy of vanilla Ubuntu 16.04.  I booted to the CD and got the same error!  I've also tried using the `forcepae` boot parameter which often does miracles on older machines, but got the same error.  I'm no expert, so I can't tell what's going on here.  I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: You need non pae kernel, if you have processor that doesn't support PAE.  On ubuntu 16.04 i think there is non pae version available.

Comment: Thanks, where would I find the non-pae kernel?

Comment: PAE kernels became the norm during the life of 11.04/kernel 2.6 (*I remember troubles when my then laptop needed the forcepae [buggy intel cpu reported non-PAE when it was PAE]*) so you'll be using something really old.   Your CPU is pentium-III era (i586 probably & not the marketing label i686 you mention) & assumed CPU operands in more modern kernels won't exist on it.  i686 is minimum 32bit currently, not i586 I think yours is.  `lspcu` will report what flags exist on your cpu & which I'd do from a 'live'  (a pentium 4 reports as i686 using 19.10/kernel 5.3)

Comment: @guiverc So I need to use an Ubuntu version with a different kernel?  (Sorry if I'm acting like an idiot; I'm not an expert on low-level stuff).

Comment: The best bet is to find the capabilities of your cpu; if you know the intel model of the cpu (eg. my current box has a 9400) you can look online; and model is specific to cpu not Core2Quad this cpu was marketed as), or go look using tools like `lshw -C cpu'  (list hardware class cpu) though older cpu's often don't provide much, eg. a pentium M only reports itself as a "M" not it's model, but the "flags" line is your cpu capabilities, ie. "fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr mce cx8 ..." for my model M which has PAE but doesn't list it due intel bug.

Comment: I had a quick look at intel.com, no celeron i686 is listed and it suggests an Intel Celeron D Processor 331 (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/27115/intel-celeron-d-processor-331-256k-cache-2-66-ghz-533-mhz-fsb.html) so you need to work out exactly what you have, as marketing names like "Celeron i686" aren't what matters.   A quick search on your model pulled up a HP manual for HP Pavilion zt1100/xz100 Omnibook (closest I came) but lists 20 cpus available for that model  (mostly speed differences but they can mean different cpu flags)

Comment: If you got here because you unexpectedly got this error trying to install >=20.04, check your machine has enough memory at startup. I resolved the issue simply by adjusting my VM's startup.RAM from 512 (Hyper-V default) to 1024MB